# ansible proxy host to remote host firewall to netconf port 830 not working

Tags: ssh, ansible, ssh-tunnel, juniper, netconf

I have to use an ssh proxy as a jump host to ssh first to the proxy then connect to the managed nodes on netconf TCP port 830.

The flow is Ansible->JUMPHOST:22->Firewall:830(Netconf)

I'm using ansible playbooks and ansible_netcommon_netconf for the ansible_connections settings.
the ansible_ssh_common_args are:

```
ansible_ssh_common_args= '-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o ProxyCommand="ssh -W  %h:830 {{ jh1_ip }}  -N -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null"'
```

I have tried all variations of the ansible_ssh_common_args and with netconf it does not work while the above var does establish a connection after seeing it on a sniffer I do not get a connection but if fails with this message.

```
 "msg": "Failed to request pty: [-1]"
```

.  While it works fine if I use ansible_netcommon_network_cli but this connection is only good for end to end ssh sessions and not netconf.  I know I'm missing something and any guidance is appreciated.